# ExtJS multiple listeners

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a property grid that I want to add multiple "afterrender" listeners to. Is it possible to add multiple listeners of the same type, or fire multiple functions within one listener?

I've tried:

```
afterrender: function(){...},
function(){...}
```

but it does not fire both of the functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make multiple function calls within the function callback. Below shows a full example of this...

[Working Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pq0)

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.property.Grid', {
    title: 'Properties Grid',
    width: 300,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

    functionOne: function() {
        alert("functionOne called");
    },

    functionTwo: function() {
        alert("functionTwo called");
    },

    listeners: {
        afterrender: function() {
            var me = this;
            me.functionOne();
            me.functionTwo();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Or `afterrender: Ext.Function.createSequence(this.functionOne, this.functionTwo, this)`

Comment: you can register multiple listeners directly with the addListener function itself. No need to call your self.

Answer (score 8):

Another way to call multiple functions with the same event is by using [on](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid-method-on):

```
...
initComponent: function () {
  var me = this;
  me.on('afterrender', me.functionA);
  me.on('afterrender', me.functionB);
  ...
  me.on('afterrender', me.functionN);
  me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible. you can add it with "**addListener**" function.

Comment: down voter can you explain what is the problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by calling several functions in a callback function with its all arguments, like this:

```
afterrender: function() {
    Foo.apply(this, arguments);
    Bar.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Now you can define functions `Foo` and `Bar` and it would be called with all `afterrender` callback function arguments.