# AfterRender event when is not fully rendered

Tags: extjs6

I want to set a form field value after a window is rendered.

When using the `afterrender` listener I have not the DOM element yet, so I do an "alert" and can see the window is not fully rendered when call `afterrender`

Why? how can I get the DOM elements of a Form when it pops on screen?

[ExtJS multiple listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179396/extjs-multiple-listeners)

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function ( cmp ) {
        alert('After Render');
    },
    render: function() {
        alert('Render');
    }
}
```

Both events will freeze the screen with a gray window and the alert message. Only when I hit "ok" I can see the form and its elements.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I'm using the "wrong" way to do this. Seems jQuery cannot do the job.

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function ( cmp ) {
        // This will work
        alert( Ext.getCmp("displayColumn").getValue() );

        // This will NOT work
        alert( $("#displayColumn").val() );
    }
}
```

Inspecting the element I can see its ID becomes `displayColumn-inputEl` even I have named it as

```
    fieldLabel: 'My Form Field',
    width: 330,
    id: 'displayColumn',
    name: 'displayColumn',
    allowBlank : false,
    value : 'default value'
```

So `$("#displayColumn")` will never find it.